# Convert Hex to signed Dec

Tags: c++, qt, number-formatting, qtcore

I have a problem with converting Hex values to signed Dec values. I am Using Qt and this is the sample code.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    int x=0xA92B;
    qDebug()<<x;
    return a.exec();
}
```

Now I get 43307 but I want to get -22229. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `short x = 0xA92B;` because if you use `int` it stores `0xA92B` as an unsigned number.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good idea, although note that short can be as big as an integer.

Comment: Since C++11 and if the system supports it, one can use int16_t instead of short.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you need this, but see the different Qt'ish ways and "short" below what they result. I think you will need short, unfortunately.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    int x = 0xA92B;
    short shortX = 0xA92B;
    QString hexString = QString::number(0xA92B);
    QTextStream decTextStream(&hexString);
    int d;
    decTextStream >> d;

    qDebug() << shortX;
    qDebug() << hexString.toInt();
    qDebug() << d;

    return 0;
}
```

#### Building (something similar)

```
g++ -fPIC -I/usr/include/qt -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -lQt5Core main.cpp && ./a.out
```

#### Output

```
-22229
43307
43307
```